# In Bootstrap 4, How to remove the gap between navbar and toggle menu item?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, navbar

With Bootstrap 4, there comes the default navbar template. I used that for learning, But, when i try to modify or style the css, i am going crazy. I dont understand what is causing the gap between navbar and toggle menu item?

I'm trying remove the gap, But, It difficult achieve, what I am looking for. Here is the Image : [Gap-img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDs8j.jpg)

```
<html>

<head> </head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role = "navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">   
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ea/Boostrap_logo.svg" width="22" height="22" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
    Bootstrap
  </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
<!--         <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-x"> -->
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown-divider"></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <section>
    <div class="container">
      <div id="about">
        <h1>My title</h1>
        <p>Hello World. Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium error tempore voluptas iusto. Deleniti impedit repellendus mollitia ad, repudiandae ab fugit ipsa in laboriosam culpa, aspernatur amet quo modi possimus.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque ea assumenda, soluta natus culpa debitis perspiciatis repudiandae doloremque eum repellendus fugiat corrupti aspernatur accusamus neque laborum totam voluptates error possimus.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

</body>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</html>`




.navbar-collapse {
  border: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
}

.nav-item{
   height:49px;
      margin-top: 0px;
      margin-bottom: 0px;
        padding-top:0px;
        padding-bottom:0px;
}

/*  */
.navbar-default,
.navbar-inverse {
  /* SET color for top bar*/
  background-color: darkblue;
  margin-bottom:20px;
}

.navbar-toggle {
  border: 0px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  padding: 18px;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0,200, 0.5);
  outline: none;
}

.navbar-toggle .icon-bar:nth-of-type(1) {
  height: 2px;
  top: 1px;
}
.navbar-toggle .icon-bar:nth-of-type(2) {
  height: 2px;
  top: 0.9px;
}
.navbar-toggle .icon-bar:nth-of-type(3) {
  height: 2px;
  top: 0.7px;
}
```

Can somebody help me out?

Comment: What have you tryed at this point?

Comment: Can you share all of your code, preferably in a JSFiddle or Codepen, please?

Comment: The custom CSS is causing it.

Comment: I'm sorry, i'm new to the forum. Pls find the codeped here: https://codepen.io/vino3d/pen/erdzvO

Comment: `navbar-toggle` should be `navbar-toggler` to work on Bootstrap.

Comment: Hi Fecosos, navbar-toggle seeems to be working fine. morever, I tried navbar-toggler instead of navbar-toggle but its isnt working.

Comment: h @SirExotic, please check the codepen.io/vino3d/pen/erdzvO

Comment: @vino3d Just saying that I noticed  that typo(?), the proper class in bootstrap is `navbar-toggler` since is used in their styles and scripts whereas `navbar-toggle` is not. A different issue maybe from the one you are asking, but still relevant. You should change it in your HTML and CSS before you notice is not working on mobile.

Comment: @vino3d I submitted an answer that will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at your Codepen and it seems that your `ul` has a **top** and **bottom** margin of `7.5px`, put the rule below in your code and it will remove it. The second value (**left** and **right** margin) will keep the size long enough so when you hover, the background color of the whole area is changed, and not just a part of it. If you don't know what I mean, try a 0 margin for all sides to see the difference.

CSS

```
.navbar-nav {
  margin: 0px -15px;
}
```

Comment: Wow.. it helped me. Thanking you. For a long time i didnt notice the parent div atall.

Comment: I'm glad :) Next time you can use the **Chrome Dev Tools** (Ctrl + Shift + I) and inspect the elements on your page to see where the extra *padding* or *margin* is coming from. Could you mark my answer as the solution so others can see? Thanks!

Comment: thanks again.  Really nice of you to assist guys like me.I did inspect, but couldn't find myself that's why . Asked in forum.